# "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" not setting incremented build number in XCode 12

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, build, xcode12

I have added the following script to increment my build number in XCode 12 under build phases

```
#!/bin/bash
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "${INFOPLIST_FILE}")
buildNumber=$(($buildNumber + 1))
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "${INFOPLIST_FILE}"
```

But the build number is not getting incremented. When I used an alternative script, the build number was incrementing incorrectly and ranging between 0000 to 0006. I don't really want the leading zeros but at least this script was changing the build which is why I am listing it here.

```
#!/bin/bash
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "$INFOPLIST_FILE")
buildNumber=$(($buildNumber + 1))
buildNumber=$(printf "%04d" $buildNumber)
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
```

Can someone tell me what's the issue with the first script? It used to work in the past. And I have ensured that xcode is pointing to the correct `Info.plist` file.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" 
"${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}")
buildNumber=$(($buildNumber + 1))
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" 
"${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}"
```

**AND! MAKE SURE THAT (BundleVersion) contains NUMBER!**

[screenshot xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lu6x.png)

*Run this script before:*

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion 1" "${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}"
```